# Is "I have no story to be told" correct or should it be "I do not have a story to tell"?

Tags: passive-voice, lyrics

***I do not have a story to be told*** . or ***I do not have a story to tell .***

In the "Rolling in the deep" song of Adele.

***Baby, I have no story to be told***

What if i use " ***to tell*** " here instead of " ***to be told*** "

Which one is correct ? And why ?

What is the meaning of both the sentences.

Comment: Neither statement is clear. Exactly what are you trying to say. Whatever the case, you need an article (*a* or *the*) before the word *story* or it needs to be plural (*stories*).

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61263/i-have-no-story-to-be-told-or-i-have-no-story-to-tell

Comment: Keep in mind that this is a song lyric, so the precise wording is often derived backwards.  They may start with the music, which defines the syllable count, rhythm, etc., and then find words to fit.  And the words usually need to rhyme.  So there are a lot of artistic liberties that take precedence over precise grammar.  But to "to tell" vs. "to be told":  "to tell" in this case implies that she will do the telling.  "A story to be told" could refer to her experience that could potentially be recounted by others".

Answer (score 1):

The two are both correct and mean almost the same thing.

The main difference is that one is the passive voice.

From http://writingcenter.unc.edu/handouts/passive-voice/

> “to be” + past participle = passive voice

There are several implications of passive voice, and some writing guides will tell you not to use it while others say it's fine. In my opinion, it depends on how you want to sound. Even though it doesn't strictly mean you're being passive if you use passive voice it can sound less forceful.

"It cannot break" or "it cannot be broken" mean the same thing. "Cannot be broken" is passive voice. Both are functionally the same.

There is some difference in the implication of permanence, and this is coming from my feel for it, not from any rule I know of. For example, if we're talking about something that would reverse and stay reversed, like legislation we might say "It can be reversed" (passive) if we are talking about something that does this a lot in general like a car we might say "it reverses" (active).

Comment: I think there is a difference though. "I have no story to tell" can mean a story about anything, while "I have no story to be told" means that there's no story/gossip about me. "Baby, **I** have no story to be told/But I've heard one on **you**"